# MongoError: aggreation, $match, $filter, $elemMatch, unknown operator: $dateToString

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, momentjs, nestjs, react-tsx

I want to retrieve all the users who have communicated with the page on the date entered from the front, the data structure below,

```
[
{
    "_id": "1",
    "createdAt": "2019-02-20T21:34:17.634Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-01T20:47:55.100Z",
    "fullName": "Jennifer Lieutard",
    "firstName": "Jennifer",
    "lastName": "Lieutard",
    "conversations": [{
        "page": "1000",
        "messages": [
            {
            "content": "lorem ipsum",
            "date":  "2019-09-23T10:40:59.394Z"
            },
            {
             "content": "lorem not ipsum",
             "date": "2019-09-23T10:51:56.165Z"
            },
            {...}
        ]
    }]
    
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "createdAt": "2019-02-20T21:34:17.634Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-01T20:47:55.100Z",
    "fullName": "Peter Pan",
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Pan",
    "conversations": [{
        "page": "1001",
        "lastMessage": "Yes they can",
        "messages": [
            {
            "content": "lorem ipsum",
            "date":  "2019-09-23T10:40:59.394Z"
            },
            {
            "content": "lorem not ipsum",
            "date": "2019-09-23T10:51:56.165Z"
            },
            {...}
        ]
    }]
}
]

/*PAGES collections*/
{
    "_id":  "5dfb43c3bc1ca6634d559685",
    "name": "All mighty",
    "updatedAt":  "2022-03-20T11:29:30.049Z"
}
```

what i did

```
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            { $eq: [{ $month: "$createdAt" },  { $month: searchByDate == 'undefined' ? new Date() : new Date(searchByDate)}] },
            { $eq: [ { $year: "$createdAt"},  { $year: searchByDate == 'undefined' ? new Date() : new Date(searchByDate)}] }
          ]
        },
        "conversations": {
          $elemMatch: {
            "page": ObjectId(pageId),
            "$and": [
              {formatedDate: {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m", date: "$createdAt" }}},
              "2019-02"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
        },
        "users": {
          $push: {
            fullName: "$fullName",
            createdDate: "$createdAt",
            formatedDate: {$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m", date: "$messages.0.date" }},
          }
        },
        "dates": {
          $push: {
            "createdAt": "$createdAt",
            "month": {
              $month: "$createdAt"
            },
            "day": {
              $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
            }
          }
        },
        count:{$sum:1}
      }
    }
```

searchByDate is (YYYY-MM) value input from the frontend, example : 2019-20,
therefore must convert the date in base of the type 2020-12-08T11:05:54.609+00:00 in 2020-12 and compared to searchByDate, and here is what I got as an error

`MongoError: unknown operator: $dateToString`

Basically the task that I want to achieve is the following

- filter to retrieve only the users who spoke to the page in the
  desired month, that is to say the conversations.page == pageId

  - Retrieve the first message in this conversation of the page, ie the message.0
  - Convert the date of this message to a Year-Month format (YYYY-MM)
  - compare this converted date to the entered value 2019-02

Comment: Why are you looking at the `$createdAt`? This is not explained in your task...

Comment: As far as I understand, if you will "filter to retrieve only the users who spoke to the page in the desired month", this does not mean that the first message in this conversation of the page is of this specific month...it can be of former months...This contradicts the first statement: "I want to retrieve all the users who have communicated with the page on the date entered from the front". Please explain